# help in figuring out a step in sum of a series

Tags: sequences-and-series

We have to find $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty kq^k$$ for $|q|<1$. The solution done by my professor was the following.

$$\begin{align*}
S&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty kq^k=\sum_{k=1}^\infty kq^k=q\sum_{k=1}^\infty kq^{k-1}\\
&=q\sum_{k=1}^\infty q^{k-1}+q\sum_{k=1}^\infty(k-1)q^{k-1}\\
&=q\sum_{k=1}^\infty q^{k-1}+q\sum_{k^\prime=1}^\infty k^\prime q^{k^\prime}\\
&=q\sum_{k=1}^\infty q^{k-1}+q\cdot S
\end{align*}$$
where we substituted $k^\prime=k-1$ in the penultimate line.

I didn't get how he added $q\sum_{k=1}^\infty (k-1)q^{k-1}$ in the second line. For my background, I am in my first year of computer science engineering, and I have done Analysis II.

Comment: Some tips to make your question better and to attract more answers than downvotes: 1) don't rely on images hosted on third-party sites (upload them here instead!) 2) don't just post a question with no explanation and expect help. How are we to know exactly which part you didn't get if you don't tell us? 3) a bit more info on your mathematical level would be helpful; an explanation would be no use to you if it's too advanced for where you're currently at and would perhaps be patronizing if we assume it to be too low.

Comment: Moreover, your professor has assumed this series is convergent, which you should also prove before using it.

Comment: u should be happy i even spent the time to learn LATEX

Comment: $$q\sum_{k=1}^\infty (k-1)q^{k-1} + q\sum_{k=1}^\infty q^{k-1} = q\sum_{k=1}^\infty \left( (k-1)q^{k-1} + q^{k-1}\right) = q\sum_{k=1}^\infty (k - 1 + 1)q^{k-1} = q\sum_{k=1}^\infty kq^{k-1}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He did not add it. Note that
$$kq^{k-1}=(\color{green}{k-1}+\color{blue}{1})q^{k-1}=(\color{green}{k-1})q^{k-1}+\color{blue}{1}q^{k-1}$$
Therefore,
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty kq^{k-1}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty(k-1)q^{k-1}+\sum_{k=1}^\infty q^{k-1}$$
and so
$$q\sum_{k=1}^\infty kq^{k-1}=q\sum_{k=1}^\infty(k-1)q^{k-1}+q\sum_{k=1}^\infty q^{k-1}$$

Hope this helps. :)